# What are the sensors available to measure liquid levels?

Tags: sensors, esp32

What is the best sensor which can be integrated with esp32 and can be used to measure liquid level in a tank. I used HCSR04 and JSN but both of them were not good. Are there any other recommendations other than these?

I wanted to measure waterlevels in tanks and sumps.

Issues with HCSR04:

- Not water resistant.

Issues with JSN:

- Blind spot of 20cm. And when I connect the device with 12v and use LM2596 and power up the device it shows error readings.

[image]

Comment: Which is "best" questions tend to lead to opinion based answers which are normally considered off topic. Please edit the question to give a lot more detail about the specific situation you are trying to measure (type of liquid, type of container) and explain why the 2 options you mention didn't work (just saying they are not good is not helpful).

Comment: @hardillb thanks for the suggestion. Edited the question

Comment: I don't think this Q is really in scope, but per a recent internal discussion, standard way to measure fluid level is ultrasonics.

Comment: Probably on-topic on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/